# iCarousel doesn't show my images objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, icarousel

i want to display multiple images in a view controller using iCarousel.

i list all my images in NSMutableArray **foto**, 
and then i called the array foto in iCarousel method **viewForItemAtIndex**.
i've followed some tutorial but still doesn't work. 
please help me.

here's my .m code

```
#import "TestController.h"

@interface TestController ()  <UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *foto;


@end


@implementation TestController


@synthesize carousel;
@synthesize foto;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        foto = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Seleb1.jpg"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Seleb2.jpg"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Seleb3.jpg"],
                     nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{

    carousel.delegate = nil;
    carousel.dataSource = nil;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.carousel = nil;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [foto count];
}



- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[foto objectAtIndex:index]]];
    return view;
}

@end
```

can someone help me ?
what is wrong with my code ?

**Updated Code**

```
#import "TestController.h"

@interface TestController ()  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *foto;


@end


@implementation TestController


@synthesize carousel;
@synthesize foto;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        foto = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"Seleb1.jpg",
                @"Seleb2.jpg",
                @"Seleb3.jpg",
                nil];
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)dealloc
{

    carousel.delegate = nil;
    carousel.dataSource = nil;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    [carousel reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.carousel = nil;

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [foto count];
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)]; // set the frame for your Image

    UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[foto objectAtIndex:index]];
    ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;

    return view;

}

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option          withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    //customize carousel display

    return value+0.1;
}

@end
```

Comment: You're not settings your iCarousel's delegate nor datasource to your viewcontroller.

Comment: @TomKnapen : where should i set it ? if it's on the story board, i've set it already. in the TestController.h, i've set it too here's my code in .h : 
TestController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>

Comment: In that case, shouldn't you be calling `[carousel reloadData]` (for example in your `viewDidLoad`)?

Comment: @TomKnapen : i've try adding [carousel reloadData] in viewDidLoad method, but still doesn't worka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my code by combining all your answer, thankyou so much. here's my new code :

```
#import "TestController.h"

@interface TestController ()  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *foto;


@end


@implementation TestController


@synthesize carousel;
@synthesize foto;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)dealloc
{

    carousel.delegate = nil;
    carousel.dataSource = nil;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    carousel.delegate = self;

    carousel.dataSource = self;
   foto = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Seleb1.jpg",
                   @"Seleb2.jpg",
                   @"Seleb3.jpg",
                   nil];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    [carousel reloadData];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.carousel = nil;

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)foto.count);
    return [foto count];
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)]; // set the frame for your Image

    UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[foto objectAtIndex:index]];
    ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;

    return view;

}

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option          withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    //customize carousel display

    return value+0.1;
}

@end
```

Thank you so much for all your answer, i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
 view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[foto objectAtIndex:index]]];
```

to

> Reason : you have already defined your array as `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Seleb1.jpg"]` , so in here you need call directly like

```
view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[foto objectAtIndex:index]];
```

**Choice-2**

create a array like

```
  foto = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"Seleb1.jpg",
                 @"Seleb2.jpg",
                 @"Seleb3.jpg",
                 nil];
```

and call like

```
 view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[foto objectAtIndex:index]]];
```

if you need

use this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
[carousel reloadData];
}
```

**Update answer**

```
  - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)]; // set the frame for your Image

          UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[foto objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;

        return view;

}
```

Comment: Nice catch, but I think this should be complemented with `[carousel reloadData]`

Comment: @TomKnapen -- I think no need of this in here ,but if we use it will be benefit

Comment: @TomKnapen - tanx buddy

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i tried both choice, but it's still doesn't work :(

Comment: well I got it , just wait

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i tried your update answer, but still didn't work :(

Comment: @Shasapo - can you send your project to my mail ID karthik.saral@gmail.com, I will try my self

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it's work finally, thank you anbu. i've posted my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

> @TomKnapen : where should i set it ? if it's on the story board, i've
>   set it already. in the TestController.h, i've set it too here's my
>   code in .h : TestController : UIViewController  – Shasapo

I'm not sure about how you are setting it in storyboard, but in code, you are not setting the delegate. This line doesn't set the delegate `TestController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource,iCarouselDelegate>`, what it does is it makes you controller, which is TestController in this case, comply to the iCarouselDelegate protocol. What you have to do is explicitly set the delegate and datasource in `viewDidLoad`,for example, i.e.

> carousel.delegate = self;
>
> carousel.datasource = self;

2 - try debugging those delegate methods first. Start with nimberOfItems method, check if foto array isnt nil. Then in viewForItem method check if the image that you return isn't nil. 
Because you are using storyboard, your initWithNibName method not getting called, that is why you foto array not getting initialized, I assume. In my opinion your numberofitems method returns 0. Try to put breakpoint int this method and see, or just add a NSLog statement and check if foto array isnt nil

3 - You are not adding iCarousel view to your view.

I have used this framework in the past, so I decided to include a snippet of the code I implemented

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (void)iCarouselSetup {
    self.view.backgroundColor = kAppColor;

    self.carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, calendarBar.bottom + 10, self.view.width, self.view.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.carousel];

    self.carousel.delegate = self;
    self.carousel.dataSource = self;
    self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow;
    self.carousel.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:2 animated:NO];

    self.currentProjectsTableview = (UITableView*)[self.carousel currentItemView]; }

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel {
    return 5; }

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    self.projectsTableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.projectsTableview.x = 0;
    self.projectsTableview.y = calendarBar.bottom;
    self.projectsTableview.width = [ASize screenWidth];
    self.projectsTableview.height = [ASize screenHeight] - 180;
    self.projectsTableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);
    self.projectsTableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor fromRGB:0xF8F8F8];
    self.projectsTableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.projectsTableview.dataSource = self;
    self.projectsTableview.delegate = self;
    self.projectsTableview.tag = tableTag++;

    return self.projectsTableview; }

- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    self.carousel.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [AppDelegate getDelegate].deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckFullViewPanning;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        for (int i = 0; i < self.carousel.numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            [self.carousel itemViewAtIndex:i].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.1f, 1.1f);
        }
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            for (int i = 0; i < self.carousel.numberOfItems; i++)
            {
                [self.carousel itemViewAtIndex:i].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.0f, 1.0f);
                [self.carousel itemViewAtIndex:i].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            }
        } ];
        tableMinimized = NO;
    }];

    self.currentProjectsTableview = (UITableView*)[carousel itemViewAtIndex:index]; }

- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel {
    [navButton setTitle:self.projectDates[self.carousel.currentItemIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }
```

Comment: try debugging those delegate methods first. Start with nimberOfItems method, check if foto array isnt nil. Then in viewForItem method check if the image that you return isn't nil.

Comment: Because you are using storyboard, your initWithNibName method not getting called, that is why you foto array not getting initialized, I assume. In my opinion your numberofitems method returns 0. Try to put breakpoint int this method and see, or just add a NSLog statement and check if foto array isnt nil

Comment: yep, i tried to print foto.count and it returns 0.

where should i put breakpoint ?
what is breakpoint by the way ?

Comment: Breakpoint is used for debugging, to make the program stop at that point in the code where you put the breakpoint. But you don't need it now, because I pointed you to the problem. Now what you need to do is get rid of that initwithnib method and use a simple init method and create you foto array in there, or just create it in viewdidload. And checked the code snippet I included in my original answer.

Comment: yep it works now, i move the foto array in viewDidLoad now it works, thankyou, i'll update my answer

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can mark my answer as accepted then so that others would know that it was helpful :)